# if I use box2d as physics engine in cocos2djs project, can i package it to android apk?

Tags: cocos2d-js, physics-engine

I'm going write a html5 game use cocos2djs, I'm new guy for cocos2djs,
my project will need to package to android apk,
I need physics engine in the game, box2d or Chipmunk which one should I chose?

Answer (score 2):

you can use box 2d or chipmunk2d as you wish you can build android package using any of them. in both the cases you have to declare which physics engine you are using in your project.json.